# Curry Lodash functions, strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to curry a lodash function and I'm getting some strange behavior. Basically:

```
function(item){return _.curryRight(myFunction)('const')(item)}
```

is not the same as

```
_.curryRight(myFunction)('const')
```

My guess is that the problem arises because functions in lodash have different arity whether you want to chain them.

I've observed that behavior with maxBy

```
var myArrays = [[{variable : 1}, {variable : 2}], [{variable : 3}, {variable : 2}]];
```

This returns the expected result

```
_.map(myArrays, function(item){return _.maxBy(item, 'variable')})
> [ { variable: 2 }, { variable: 3 } ]
```

We obtain the same behavior if we curry maxBy inside the function

```
_.map(myArrays, function(item){return _.curryRight(_maxBy)('variable')(item)})
> [ { variable: 2 }, { variable: 3 } ]
```

However, the following does not work

```
_.map(myArrays, _.curryRight(_.maxBy)('variable'))
>[undefined, undefined]
```

So basically the question is, why is the last method not returning the same as the previous two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to `curryRight` to work, `'variable'` would have to be the second argument.

However, when using the `_.map` function `'variable'` arrives as fourth argument.

This is basically the same error as what happens when doing `_.map(array, parseInt)`, the result will be unexpected because `parseInt` will receive index as second argument and use it as base

Answer (score 0):

```
_.map(myArrays, _.curryRight(_.maxBy)('variable'))
```

This case, not working because, second argument for _.maxBy - must be the string 'variable'. You can go to lodash source in developer tools and find method _.maxBy them. Write "console.log" in this source file and save it (Ctrl+s).

```
function maxBy(array, iteratee) {
  console.log(arguments);
  return (array && array.length)
    ? baseExtremum(array, getIteratee(iteratee), gt)
    : undefined;
}
```

Run in console

```
_.map(myArrays, _.curryRight(_.maxBy)('variable'))
```

and you watch:

```
[Array[2], 1, Array[2], "variable"]
```

In method _.maxBy firstly passed all arguments for _.map iteratee function https://lodash.com/docs#map and after that string 'variable'.

Use:

```
_.map(myArrays, _.flow(_.identity,  _.curryRight(_.maxBy)('variable')));
```

it's work correctly.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: But then, why does funcion(item){ return _.curryRight(_maxBy)('variable')(item)} work? Wouldn't it have the same problem?

Comment: For this case, all arguments for _.map iteratee function passed in an anonymous function. We can rewrite it like this: function(item, index, collection) { return _.curryRight(_.maxBy)('variable')(item) }
But, this function return carried _.maxBy method, that takes only item and 'variable';